# calling SQL Server Endpoint web service

Tags: json, soap, endpoints

I understand that SQL Server endpoint returns data using SOAP.
Does anyone know if they can return JSON data?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native HTTP endpoints can only return SOAP messages.

However it's possible to switch off the generation of the SOAP envelope, if you specify `FORMAT = NONE` in the `FOR SOAP` section of the declaration.
You could use this to provide an HTTP wrapper to your own stored procedure(s) which JSON-ise SQL server data (see [books online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181591.aspx) for a detailed description of the very specific requirements your procedure must fulfill).

You should be aware that native endpoints are [deprecated in SQL 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280436.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[No, unfortunately they don't support JSON](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-endpoints-soup-to-nuts/).